# Use external class library as model class for Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I'm novice to Laravel and PHP.

I wrote a standard PHP library which defines a GpxWaypoint class. This class declare some properties (latitude, longitude, altitude, name) and defines some methods (getDistance($anotherWaypoint), getAscent($anotherWaypoint)) and obviously doesn't extends Eloquent Model class.

```php
class GpxWaypoint
{
    private $latitude;      
    private $longitude;     
    .......
```

Then I wrote for testing a Waypoint class in Laravel, with the same attributes of the standard GpxWaypoint class.

```php
class Waypoint extends Model
{

   public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }
}
```

```php
class CreateWaypointsTable extends Migration
{
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('waypoints', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->string('name', 128);
            $table->decimal('latitude', 32, 28);
            $table->decimal('longitude', 32, 28);
            $table->integer('altitude');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

Is there a way for using the GpxWaypoint class defined in the external library as a Laravel Model class?
In composer.json I added the external library as a required lib and it runs, I can instantiate GpxWaypoints objects... but I don't know how to use it as a Model class.

I'd like to use the GpxWaypoint class because it defines some methods and functionality I need in the Laravel project and I don't want to rewriting them (external lib also contains GpxFile, GpxTrack, GpsTrackSegment, GpsTrackPoint classes with their property and methods I'd like to use in my Laravel project too)

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The two classes are actually quite different. `GpxWaypoint` has member variables while `Waypoint` is backed by database attributes. It would not be a good idea to try to mix those two concepts because internally Laravel accesses attributes differently.

I would suggest extracting the shared concepts to a trait e.g:

```
trait WaypointTrait {
   public getDistance($anotherWaypoint) {
     ...
   }

}

class GpxWaypoint
{
    use WaypointTrait;
 
    private $latitude;      
    private $longitude;     
    .......

}
class Waypoint extends Model
{
   use WaypointTrait;

}
```

Comment: Very good solution. Successfully tested. Thank you very much!!!